# How can add .mp3 or .wav file in asp.net mvc project?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, audio, wav

I want to play a warning sound using javascript in the cshtml file. I want to put the audio file ( wav or mp3)  under the content directory. I want to play this file in the script using the audio library. I tried to add the file with drag and drop on top of the project but it didn't. I don't want to do a database-related operation.

Solution:
Following the steps, I added the audio file to the bottom of the folder I wanted.
"Right click > Add> Existing item"

Comment: Is this a coding question or are you just asking how to add a file in visual studio? Right click the folder where you want to add it...then choose the Add option, then select the file you want to add

Comment: Or just copy it to the folder using windows explorer, and then choose add existing item from within visual studio. Make sure after that you set it's build option to copy to output directory, otherwise it won't be copied when you build and publish your application

Comment: If you are using VS and you are debugging,  stop debugging and try drag and drop.

Comment: @ADyson teşekür ederim. I did it with "Add> Existing item". 
I had previously dragged the file and left it on the project.
 It has never been through this method.

Comment: @SudheerMuhammed I thank you for taking the time to my problem. 
It never happened in the way you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should copy the file in a directory in the project and you should let IIS know that mp3 files are legal. For doing this you have to add MIME type in your project's web.config

Please check this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52730292/asp-net-mvc-not-serving-mp3-files) for more information about how to add mp3 files mime type in web.config

Comment: I solved my problem. The information you provide is very valuable. Thank you.

Comment: your welcome. please accept my answer then. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should just need to put the audio file somewhere in your wwwroot so it'll be web-accessible when the project is built.  Then you can use the external-facing URL in your javascript to actually load and play it.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, but I need to add the sound file directly to the project. After the project is published, it is moved to another server and compiled and ready for use. I have no chance to access the server from which it was compiled. There's no other way?

Comment: The wwwroot is in the project, at least for an ASP.NET project...  So, I'm not sure what you mean otherwise.  But yeah, for a web-based application, you have to serve the audio as a separate file.  There's no way to "embed" audio into a webpage.